# connecting two bluetooth low energy devices with their uuid's and display their RSSI value

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

can anyone help me to connect two BLEs with the help of their uuids. also how to display their RSSI value both.

```
 (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {    
      discoverPeripherals=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      _CBManager=[[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
      NSDictionary *options=@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]};    
      NSArray *servicesUUIDsList=@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TX_POWER_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BATTERY_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID]];
      [self.CBManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:servicesUUIDsList options:options];

 }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Core Bluetooth programming guide? Have you implemented the CBCentralManager delegate methods?

Comment: yah i implemented all the delegate methods

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried to connect to a peripheral?  There is plenty of sample code available if you search or read the Apple programming guide

Comment: -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{[[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]isEqualToString:@"02D0D956-B0ED-D802-0000-000000000000"];{peripheral.delegate=self;[self.CBManager connectPeripheral:peripheral1 options:nil];}[[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]isEqualToString:@"E2297F70-FD3F-C325-0000-000000000000"];{peripheral.delegate=self;
 [self.CBManager connectPeripheral:peripheral2 options:nil];
    }
}

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code so that it can be formatted properly